# We cause the tears but not the cry

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

We're concerned with who but never why,
We cause the tears but not the cry.
We're from a world that's found by you,
Where two is one and one is two.

What are we?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you are

> Vowels

We're concerned with who but never why,

> *who* has a vowel but *why* doesn't (in this instance, we don't count 'y')

We cause the tears but not the cry.

> *tears* has two vowels but *cry* does not have any.

We're from a world that's found by you,

> Vowels are representations of vocal sounds constructed by humans.

Where two is one and one is two.

> *two* has one vowel, *one* has two.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, as I've never known y to be considered a vowel, am I missing something? Confused about the "In this instance, we don't count 'y'"

Comment: @David It can be either. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/is-the-letter-y-a-vowel-or-a-consonant

Comment: But isn't Y being used as a vowel in the first two lines?

Comment: @Irishpanda The Y creates a vowel sound in these cases but isn't a true vowel letter.

Comment: For two is one and one is two, I instantly thought of "ea" making one sound (ee) and "i" making 2 (ah-ee)

Comment: That's less a confusion on whether y is or is not a 'real vowel' and more an issue with English being so internally confused that it can't even differentiate its letters consistently.

Comment: The "y" in "cry" is considered a vowel, whereas the "y" in "your" is not.

Comment: A great riddle! I think the third line would be stronger as "We're from a world that ends with you", though I'm perhaps missing the intended clue as is.

Comment: @DainIIIronfoot The 'we' in this riddle are the conventional vowels: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_words_without_vowels

Comment: @xnor I wrote it simply as vowels are in *world* and *you*, (and *world* helped form the next line) but I like this answer's interpretation

Comment: +1 @rybo111 and TimB for the interesting reads.  I remember being tought at school that Y was a substitute-vowel or a semi-vowel.  This concept annoyed me, like most of the caveats in English lessons...

Great answer as always hexomino